# connection between angular and node

Tags: node.js, angular

I have an angular app and I want to connect to node.js server. My question is how to do that? Do I have to write any code on my angular app to set the connection and then send the http request or just send the requests to the server? (I have all the API's ens points).
When I just send the request I get 404 error.

```
export class ApiConnectionService { 
    uri = "http://dev.cantinadigital.co.il:8080";
    constructor(private http: HttpClient) { } 
    postContactUsMessage(message: Object): Observable<any> {
        return this.http.post(${this.uri}/contactus, message); 
    }
}
```

Comment: paste your code please...

Comment: I do not think that the problem is in my code. I think that something wrong with the way of doing that. I just make the request and maybe I need first to set any connection or do something like in this article https://medium.freecodecamp.org/the-best-ways-to-connect-to-the-server-using-angular-cli-b0c6b699716c

Answer (score 0):

If you have Angular app working for example on 'localhost:3000' and node server on 'localhost:5000' You have to send request to node server address. So if you want to get for example list of todo's you have to send 'GET' request to 'localhost:5000/todos'. But if it all works on one port, You just send request to '/todos' and that should work well.

Answer (score 0):

You just send a request to your server.

For Example:

```
    public doSomething(): Promise<any> {
       var url = "localhost:8081/api/test";
       return this.http.get(url, option).toPromise();
    }
```

When you call the function, don't forget its asynchronous:

```
doSomething().then(result => ....)
```

Also you have to adjust your proxy settings, so you have to add an entry in proxy.conf.json

If you get a 404 maybe your server setup is not working. So maybe it would be best if you check with Postman, if you can reach your url.

Answer (score 0):

I made a demo for you to how to deal with the Http calls and Api in angular and put you a comment in what you should change to work with your case:
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-service-intro?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.service.ts

Hope this helps you